# Diferença no parâmetro do onCreate(Bundle)

Tags: android, parâmetros

Me surgiu uma duvida aqui lendo o livro do Ricardo Lecheta, de android, na qual não vi explicação nem no livro, nem achei na internet. Alguns exemplos ele utiliza a função onCreate dessa forma: onCreate(Bundle icicle) e outras onCreate(Bundle savedSInstanceState). Alguém poderia explicar a diferença entre os dois parâmetros?

Comment: Os dois são do mesmo tipo, então, iguais, agora a diferença está na grafia que pode simbolizar algo na programação, algo próprio ou seguindo alguma regra

Comment: Então eu utilizo qualquer um dos dois que não afetará em nada, correto?

Comment: Sim, porque, o que vale é `Bundle` o nome da variavel pouco importa nesse aspecto. Agora pode simbolizar como eu disse um regra ou algo próprio para ele saber diferenciar no código ou algo parecido

Comment: Entendi, valeu cara.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A única diferença é que o método onCreate(Bundle icicle) é de versões mais antigas do SDK do Android, enquanto onCreate(Bundle savedSInstanceState) está nas versões mais novas.

Repare o seguinte: em ambas as versões, o parâmetro de entrada é um Bundle, e a única coisa que mudou foi o nome da "variável" dada a esse parâmetro de entrada. Ou seja, eles são a mesma coisa.